# Java Google Spreadsheet "Token Invalid - AuthSub token has wrong scope"

Tags: java, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to authorize requests to be made to google spreadsheets. Here is the code I use to obtain the credential:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream p12 = GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.p12");

        File file = new File("hi");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(p12, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("8429209348-1nfuorcfko5pmqh2l0b1au968igchaoq@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .build();
        return credential;
    }
```

This is the code in another class where it obtains the credential and calls `SpreadsheetService.setOAuth2Credential(credential);`

```
static{
    service = new SpreadsheetService("Main");
    try {
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(GoogleUtils.authorize());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this I get this exact error.

[image]

I'm almost positive that there isn't anything wrong with the p12 key because I've tested this exact same code in another project and all the directory/file stuff work out. I've tried obtaining new p12 keys, but to no avail. If there is something I'm missing, I'd be glad to hear it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong scopes the entire time :/